# Shared memory is not so shared with processes in C

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, fork, shared-memory

While trying to resolve some debugging issues , I added some `printf`-s to my code :

I used that code :

```
struct PipeShm
{
    int init;
    sem_t sema;
        ...
        ...
}

struct PipeShm * sharedPipe = NULL;
```

func2:

```
int func2()
{
if (!sharedPipe)
{

    int myFd = shm_open ("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (myFd == -1)
        error_out ("shm_open");

    // allocate some memory in the region in the size of the struct
    int retAlloc = ftruncate (myFd, sizeof * sharedPipe);
    if (retAlloc < 0)  // check if allocation failed
        error_out("ftruncate");

    // map the region and shared in with all the processes
    sharedPipe = mmap (NULL, sizeof * sharedPipe,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED , myFd, 0);

    if (sharedPipe == MAP_FAILED)  // check if the allocation failed
        error_out("mmap");

    // put initial value
    int value = -10;
    // get the value of the semaphore
    sem_getvalue(&sharedPipe->semaphore, &value);


    if (sharedPipe->init != TRUE) // get in here only if init is NOT TRUE !
    {
        if (!sem_init (&sharedPipe->semaphore, 1, 1)) // initialize the semaphore to 0
        {

            sharedPipe->init = TRUE;
            sharedPipe->flag = FALSE;
            sharedPipe->ptr1 = NULL;
            sharedPipe->ptr2 = NULL;
            sharedPipe->status1 = -10;
            sharedPipe->status2 = -10;
            sharedPipe->semaphoreFlag = FALSE;
            sharedPipe->currentPipeIndex = 0;
            printf("\nI'm inside the critical section! my init is: %d\n" , sharedPipe->init);

        }
        else
            perror ("shm_pipe_init");
        printf("\nI'm out the critical section! my init is: %d\n" , sharedPipe->init);

    }


}
return 1;   // always successful
}
```

With that main :

```
int main()

{
    int spd, pid, rb;
    char buff[4096];
    fork();
    func2();
    return 0;
}
```

And got this :

shm_pipe_mkfifo: File exists

```
I'm inside the critical section! my init is: 1

I'm out the critical section! my init is: 1
Output:hello world!
I'm inside the critical section! my init is: 1

I'm out the critical section! my init is: 1
```

It seems that the shared memory is not so shared , why ?

1. The segment is shared between all processes due to `MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS` , so why both processes have the same `before` and `after` values ?
2. It seems that each process has its own semaphore even though it was shared between them , so what went wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: You've already been shown how to properly use semaphores in another question; why do you insist on not doing so?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Updated , please see at the end of the post .

Comment: @ron, given the amount of help you get from people on SO for this single project, you should really indicate SO as co-author of your code when you submit the finished project :)

Comment: @HristoIliev: All rights reserved to SO...

Comment: @HristoIliev: BTW my friend , I never ask ANYONE to solve my HW for me. I always ask a question where I present my code , and what I did so far.

Comment: @ron, no need to bring strawman arguments, my friend - I haven't said that someone on SO wrote your code in the first place and obviously you are not clueless about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you use the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag to `mmap`, the `myFd` argument is ignored, and you create two independent shared memory chunks, one in each process, which have no relation to each other.

> ```
>   MAP_ANONYMOUS
>           The mapping is not backed by any file; its contents are initial‐
>           ized to zero.  The fd and offset arguments are ignored; however,
>           some implementations require fd to be -1  if  MAP_ANONYMOUS  (or
>           MAP_ANON)  is specified, and portable applications should ensure
>           this.  The use of MAP_ANONYMOUS in conjunction  with  MAP_SHARED
>           is only supported on Linux since kernel 2.4.
> ```

If you get rid of `MAP_ANONYMOUS` you'll then only have one shared memory chunk, but you then have the problem of not calling `sem_init`.  On Linux with NPTL it will actually work, as clearing a sem_t to all 0 bytes (the initial state here) is equivalent to `sem_init(&sema, anything, 0);` (NPTL ignores the pshared flag), but that's not portable to other systems.

Per Karoly's comment on another answer, there's also a race condition due O_TRUNC on the open call.  If the second thread calls `open` after the first thread has already started modifying the semaphore, that TRUNC will clobber the semaphore state.  Probably the best solution is to move the code creating, opening, and mmaping the shared memory to a different function that is called BEFORE calling fork.

**edit**

To fix the O_TRUNC problem, you can't have more than one process calling shm_open with O_TRUNC.  But if you just get rid of the O_TRUNC, then you have the startup problem that if the shared memory object already exists (from a previous run of the program), it may not be in a predictable state.  On possibility is to split off the beginning of func2:

```
main() {
    func1();
    fork();
    func2();
}

func1() {
    int myFd = shm_open ("/myregion", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0666);
    if (myFd == -1)
        error_out ("shm_open");
    // allocate some memory in the region in the size of the struct
    int retAlloc = ftruncate (myFd, sizeof *sharedPipe);
    if (retAlloc < 0)  // check if allocation failed
        error_out("ftruncate");
    // map the region and shared in with all the processes
    sharedPipe = mmap (NULL, sizeof *sharedPipe, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, myFd, 0);
    if (sharedPipe == MAP_FAILED)  // check if the allocation failed
        error_out("mmap");
}

func2() {
    // put initial value
    int value = -10;
    // get the value of the semaphore
    sem_getvalue(&sharedPipe->semaphore, &value);

    :
```

Alternately you could keep the same code (just get rid of O_TRUNC) and add a cleanup before the fork:

```
main() {
    shm_unlink("/myregion");
    fork();
    func2();
```

In all cases you'll still have problem if you run multiple copies of your program at the same time.

Comment: ,how can I avoid the race condition here ? they're indeed racing

Comment: @ron: move the racing code (shm_open at least, possibly the ftruncate and mmap as well) to a separate function that is only called once, before the fork.

Comment: Thanks for your tremendous help , but one thing is still not so clear : if I want to run multiple processes with my program , let's take the basic example of a single `fork` before `func2()` (the `func2` in `main()`) then in "normal life" , that supposed to possible , right ? to be frank with you , I'm still trying to improve my code with your great suggestions , but I still get here and there some race conditions ...

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts...

1. I think this is a fundemental misunderstanding of how POSIX semaphores work.  I don't see a call to `sem_init` or `sem_open`.  You shouldn't be able to use them across processes without doing so much more explicitly than you've done.
2. I'm not so fresh on the implementation of `mmap` on Linux and how `MAP_ANONYMOUS` might affect this, but in general writes to mapped regions can't really be instantaneous.  The [manpage on linux.die says](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap):

> MAP_SHARED
> Share this mapping. Updates to the mapping are visible to other processes that map this file, and are carried through to the underlying file. The file may not actually be updated until msync(2) or munmap() is called.

The reason for this is that your memory access gets trapped in a page fault and at that point the kernel will fill contents from the file descriptor, then let you do your write in RAM, then at some later point the kernel will flush back to the file descriptor.

Comment: ther are probably many more problems, eg: `O_TRUNC`. flushing is not an issue, he doesn't read from the disk.

Comment: It's not really a file; it's shared memory.  As in the same RAM mapped into two different processes.  You are correct that the bugs are here are (a) not calling sem_init with pshared=1, and (b) using MAP_ANONYMOUS which is wrong in this case.